# package ‘pbkrtest’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

Tags: r, install.packages

I want to install the package "car" but it depends of a package "pbkrtest" I can't install :

> ERROR: dependency ‘pbkrtest’ is not available for package ‘car’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
>    install.packages("pbkrtest")
>   Installing package into ‘/home/d9999/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     ****package **‘pbkrtest’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)******

Do you have an idea ?

R Studio version : 0.99.489
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Answer (score 31):

According to the [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/index.html), the current version of the package `pbkrtest` (v0.4.6) requires R v. 3.2.3 or higher.

> Depends:  R (≥ 3.2.3)

Since `car` depends on `pbkrtest`, you need to upgrade your R version to the latest version in order to use this package.

Alternatively, you can install an older version of `pbkrtest` (0.4.4 or higher), which you can find [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/pbkrtest/). Version 0.4.5 of `pbkrtest` could be a good choice if you don't want to or cannot upgrade R, because this version would be sufficient to install the latest version of `car`, and it could operate on your current R version since it requires only R v3.0.2 or higher.

Comment: `packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/pbkrtest/pbkrtest_0.4-4.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")`  Maybe you also  need to update or reinstall package `lm4`

Comment: Just an FYI for future readers, to get @EnriquePérezHerrero 's installation code above to work, I had to install `lme4` first; `install.packages("lme4")`, then run Enrique's code to install `pbkrtest`, and finally get to installing `car`.

Comment: Thanks @EnriquePérezHerrero I also had to add argument `method="curl"` for this trick to work

Comment: Final note: @EnriquePérezHerrero's answer is two lines, not one.

Comment: How to install the .tar.gz file: [Manish Barnwal - How to install a package of a particular version in R](http://manishbarnwal.com/blog/2016/10/05/install_a_package_particular_version_in_R/).