# R 3.2.2 Caret Package Load error : "there is no package called ‘pbkrtest’"

Tags: r

I am having a hard time loading the Caret package. Apologies for the triviality of this question. Currently using R 3.2.2 "Fire Saftey" - I do not have the ability to upgrad to 3.3.0 currently. I have tried looking at the caret historical archive and manually downloading via r studio an older version of the package; this has not worked either. Help me out. See below for error that occurs when I load caret.

```
> library(caret)

Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
there is no package called ‘pbkrtest’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’

>
```

Comment: What happens when you `install.packages('caret')` and/or `install.packages('pbkrtest')`?

Comment: Search CRAN for the right source version and install.

Comment: Here's a shameless reference to one of my own answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35207929/4770166

Comment: @mathematical.coffee caret will install but will not load . pbkrtest would not install via `install.packages('pbkrtest')` , however it installed via downloading the actual package ZIP file and manually installing via R studio - Now that pbkrtest is installed, caret will load. Thanks