# IV Regression in R - could not find function "linearHypothesis"

Tags: r, regression

I am very new to R, and trying to reproduce a Stata Output. I have the following Regression

```
formula2 <- as.formula(paste("lnwd ~  dreformd + ", paste("", PredictorVar2,  collapse='+'), "+", paste("", PredictorYr, collapse='+')))
```

with dreformd being endogenous. I want to run a 2SLS by regressing dreformd on three instruments

```
datatwo$qz1 <- factor (with (datatwo, ifelse ((q1 == 1), 1, 0)))
datatwo$qz2 <- factor (with (datatwo, ifelse ((q1 == 2), 1, 0)))
datatwo$qz3 <- factor (with (datatwo, ifelse ((q1 == 0|q1 == 3), 1, 0)))
```

This would be my code:

```
library(car)
iv = ivregress(formula2, dreformd ~ qz1 + z2 + qz3, datatwo)
```

And all I get as Output is

```
Error in ivregress(formula2, dreformd ~ qz1 + qz2 + qz3, datatwo) : 
could not find function "linearHypothesis"
```

I am lost here, I've tried everything and have no clue where the problem is. I've also tried using the ivreg function, but R cannot find that one either. The AER and CAR packages are installed. What am I missing ?

EDIT: tried installing CAR and AER with dependencies, still get the same error. The car package cannot load, and there is no pbkrtest package. Tried installing it, I get this error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘pbkrtest’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

Comment: Loading the `AER` package? Have you tried library(AER)?

Comment: is [this](https://gist.github.com/tony91782/950834#file-ivregress-r-L34) where you are getting that function?

Comment: I've loaded it, doesn't change anything. I just get an error message that the car package could not be loaded (not sure why this happens when trying to load AER) @Alex

Comment: @rawr yes, exactly

Comment: As hinted by Alex, `AER` has a `ivreg` function. There is also a package called `ivpack` that might be worth a look.

Comment: Tried using ivreg as well, all I get is Error: could not find function "ivreg"

Comment: I'm not getting this error. are you sure `library('car')` works without error?

Comment: Do you have `AER` installed and loaded? `install.packages(AER, dependencies=TRUE); library(AER)`.

Comment: Yes I do, when I load AER I get an error though

    `Lade nötiges Paket: car`
    `Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
    es gibt kein Paket namens ‘pbkrtest’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Paket ‘AER’ wurde unter R Version 3.2.5 erstellt 
2: Paket ‘car’ wurde unter R Version 3.2.5 erstellt 
Error: Paket ‘car’ konnte nicht geladen werden`

Comment: Basically it tells me there is no package named "pbkrtest" (whatever that is) and that the car package could not be loaded.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that all other packages are working fine, and regular regressions run smoothly as well. It's just the IV stuff that refuses to cooperate D:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207624/package-pbkrtest-is-not-available-for-r-version-3-2-2 maybe you are using an old version of r. then you should update the packages after updating r. check your `sessionInfo()` and add it to your question

Comment: Have you updated R? The current stable Version is 3.3.0 .

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this too. 
You have to install `car`. R is going to ask you to install several other packages in the process. I went one by one (as far as I remember there were 7 or 8 different packages) and at the end could run `library(car)` and then R accept  the function `linearHypothesis`